# Facebook Like + Send button broken?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

On the [facebook documentation page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) if you click the "Send" button in the default example, it pops open a new window that looks to be just the like/send button repeated.

I take it this is because it's broken in some way, either that or my browser (and that of my colleagues is severely broken)

Does anyone else suffer from the same fate?  Does anyone have a fix?

Side note - on our website this was working fine yesterday, it appears to be a new issue.

Comment: Instead of down-voting and requesting this to be closed, perhaps a comment as to why would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug report about that: [Send button opens new tab](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/177102442412197?browse=search_4f99aff6361807b29945219).
Also, looks like there are a few issues with the button as you can see in the [bugs tagged with Send Button](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs?search_view=search&search_ids%5B0%5D=119344624828659&&search_statuses%5B0%5D=open)

I haven't voted you down (I rarely do), and I have no idea what were the reasons for that, but  it is better to first research before asking a question here, as you can see it was easy to locate the bug(s) in the official facebook bugging report system, also if you search here you'll find more questions regarding this issue (and a few from today).

Comment: Sorry - I just found the bug on the Facebook developer website.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have found that the code issued by Facebook for combination Send/Button is not working as of Sept. 27 2013.  The Send button throws up a blank screen, instead of the Facebook email dialog box. This code from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ did not work. Note this applies to JavaScript code, not old IFRAME code which is being deprecated.

To see a full description with images, check out link below for a solution

http://metadataconsulting.blogspot.ca/2013/09/facebook-likesend-button-not-working.html